# SQL Server : replace email with sample text but maintain structure

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

For a SQL Server 2005 Instance what is the best way to take find/replace a column with multiple emails like

```
<JimmyTheBoot@yahoo.com>; JohnBlaze@TestMail.com; comfarmer@yahoo.com .....
```

and replace it with

```
<TestMail@yRandMail.com>; TestMail@RandMail.com; TestMail@RandMail.com .....
```

For testing purposes, I could think of some ways to do this in C# but I was wondering if there was a think way to do it in SQL Server, maybe with REGEX ? I want to keep the random weirdness as much as possible (some emails have brackets, some have semicolons at the end etc ...)

Thanks

Comment: I'd rather you do this in c# code. But you could use "LIKE" in your statement maybe...

Comment: @F. Muller I know what it is will perform like s@it ... but it is just to generate test data and I feel like if I ever have to do it again it would be more convenient to just run it in SSMS rather then VS, no ?

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna No; it would be easier if you were producing test data completely without a database involved at all, if you were using IoC or even just a simple repository pattern with a test repository that produces test data without ever touching a database. You are "testing" a lot more than you think you are by trying to complicate things like this.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I actually mocked up with sample data, however the archive application i'm writing is dependent on a preexisting data-store that has very peculiar distribution of data like say 500-1000 character To_Addr email fields that will impact the way the UI has to perform.  I can't test on the onsite data as it is sensitive so I need to generate sample data that closely models the wacky pre-existing data. Also some of the irregularities in the formatting will affect how I have to handle data.  However as a general rule I agree it would be much easier to use random sample data.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna If your problem is as you describe, I would recommend using a tool to obfuscate the data for testing, while keeping the irregularities intact. The basic problem with what you are doing is that you are inserting more application code that is solely for testing. You will have to test again once that code is removed, to assure things still work.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Could you tell me of such a tool ?

Comment: When I typed "using" I should have typed "creating".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, you can accomplish it with a cte in a function.

```
create function dbo.FixupEmails(@s varchar(8000))
returns table
as
return (
      WITH splitter_cte AS (
      SELECT CHARINDEX(';', @s) as pos, 0 as lastPos, 1 as cte_level
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CHARINDEX(';', @s, pos + 1), pos, cte_level + 1 as cte_level
      FROM splitter_cte
      WHERE pos > 0
      ), each_email_cte AS(
      select replace(replace(replace(OneEmail, '>', ''), '<', ''), ' ', '') as OneEmail, cte_level
        from (select SUBSTRING(@s, lastPos + 1,
                         case when pos = 0 then 80000 else pos - lastPos -1 end) as OneEmail,
                         cte_level
                from splitter_cte) as t
      ), each_half_cte AS (
        select OneEmail, CHARINDEX('@', OneEmail) as atPos, cte_level
        from each_email_cte
        where len(OneEmail) > 6  -- 6 from x@x.co (I think that 6 would be the minimum valid email length)
      ), new_email_cte as
      (
        select cte1.OneEmail, Replace(@s, cte1.OneEmail, 'TestMail@RandMail.com') as New, cte1.cte_level --, 1 as level
        from each_half_cte cte1
        where cte1.cte_level = 1

        UNION ALL

        select cte2.OneEmail, Replace(necte.New, cte2.OneEmail, 'TestMail@RandMail.com') as New, cte2.cte_level--, 1 as level
        from new_email_cte as necte
        inner join each_half_cte as cte2 on cte2.cte_level = necte.cte_level + 1


      )
      select New
      from new_email_cte
      where cte_level = (select max(cte_level) from new_email_cte)
)
go

set nocount on;

declare @emailString varchar(2048)
set @emailString = '<JimmyTheBoot@yahoo.com>; JohnBlaze@TestMail.com; comfarmer@yahoo.com ';
select @emailString as Original;
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.FixupEmails(@emailString);




set @emailString = '<JimmyTheBoot@yahoo.com>; JohnBlaze@TestMail.com;';
select @emailString as Original;
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.FixupEmails(@emailString);


set @emailString = '<JimmyTheBoot@yahoo.com>';
select @emailString as Original;
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.FixupEmails(@emailString)
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
-- include MAXRECURSION as shown above if you have more than 100 email addresses in the field.



set @emailString = '<bill@whatever.co.uk>; John@TestMail.tv;';
select @emailString as Original;
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.FixupEmails(@emailString)
```

It is kind of long, but here is the output.

```
Original
----------------------------------------------------------------
<JimmyTheBoot@yahoo.com>; JohnBlaze@TestMail.com; comfarmer@yahoo.com 

New
-----------------------------------------------------------------
<TestMail@RandMail.com>; TestMail@RandMail.com; TestMail@RandMail.com 




Original
----------------------------------------------------------------
<JimmyTheBoot@yahoo.com>; JohnBlaze@TestMail.com;

New
----------------------------------------------------------------
<TestMail@RandMail.com>; TestMail@RandMail.com;





Original
----------------------------------------------------------------
<JimmyTheBoot@yahoo.com>

New
----------------------------------------------------------------
<TestMail@RandMail.com>





Original
----------------------------------------------------------------
<bill@whatever.co.uk>; John@TestMail.tv;

New
----------------------------------------------------------------
<TestMail@RandMail.com>; TestMail@RandMail.com;
```

This was lots of fun.  I think that the function provided will do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

- [SQL Server String Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx)

  One approach might be:

  1. Find the index of an @ symbol
  2. Replace the part before it (until previous whitespace or other char - maybe the set [],;<>()) with your email ID
  3. Replace the part after it (until next whitespace or other char) with your domain
  4. Repeat with next @ symbol in the column

  If you happen to replace part of a friendly name and not an email
  identifier by accident, it shouldn't be important.

  Use CHARINDEX to find the next index of the @ symbol in a string.
  Use PATINDEX to find the index of a particular pattern e.g.
  whitespace or other separator characters. It might be easier to chunk
  the string out by section or split on whitespace than dealing with
  the entire thing at once.
- It might also be easier to write a regex and set up a SQL CLR function to do the replace.
- If the reason for replacing the email addresses is to avoid sending
  email to them, you could set a debug flag/option into the
  application. When the flag is set, replace an email address with a
  developer defined address or log but ignore the email sending.